# Click event transferred to next started Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, event-handling, onclick

I'm affected by strange event handling in Android. My problem is that if user clicks at a `Button` many times really quick then event is queued and transferred further to next `Activity`.

Here is an example:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn_home_show"
  style="@style/main_buttons"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/home_label_show" />
```

`Activity` `onClick`:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int viewId = view.getId();

    if (viewId == EXPECTED_VIEW_ID) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CarouselActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In my `Activity` I have another item that is clickable with the same coordinates on the screen.

What happens is that if user click really fast on the `Button` then this click event is transfered to newly started `Activity` and another `onClick` handling occurs.

I tried 2.3.3 & 2.3.5 framework version & behavior is the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be add a boolean value that determines whether or not a click is handled then create a thread that sleeps then sets the value to true

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (inputAllowed) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

boolean inputAllowed = true;
private class ButtonDelay extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            inputAllowed = false;

            Thread.sleep(500);
            inputAllowed = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

    }

}
```

And start the asynctask immediately in onCreate(). As for why this happens I guess the new activity has created the new button and since the user is rapidly clicking it registers these clicks.

Comment: This seams to be like a work-around, but this way I'm supposed to do it in every Activity I start & for every view I create. This looks bad ;-) Maybe there is a way to "reset" queue on Activity start?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to reset and there's no point if the reset happens before the last click (ie the user is still clicking away like a moron), I use this code but I have it the global Application class and integers to tell what type of input it is, the same asynctask but it takes in the integer representing the input eg back pressed and locks that type of input.

You can protect users from accidental mis-clicks like this, if they're stupidly clicking away then there's not much you can do to protect your app from their moronic actions.

Comment: Then lock the entire gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that the click event is transferred to the new activity. The problem is that after the first click that you are doing your new activity will start to appear. If the user clicks again for some times your new Activity loads and receives the click as it is supposed to do. I would assume that you are blocking the UI-Thread during your activity change and because of that the user is not sure if he has hit the button and tries to click it again.

Try to fasten up your Activity switching. You could just show an Overlay with a Spinner that catches all click events until you are ready to show the correct UI of the Activity. In that way the user realizes that something happened and will stop clicking and wait for the spinner to disappear.

Comment: You are now 100% right. Your assumption is wrong and all I do is handle onClick and do startActivity. No way it cal block UI-Thread :-) My problem is kind of "monkey testing" or "clicking like a moron" mentioned before. User clicks just few times on the activity not looking if the button was really clicked or missed. However overlay with spinner idea looks interesting to me.

Comment: The blocking can also appear in the view creation of the next activity. If you are loading a little bit complex layout in onCreate or access a shared preference file for the first time the onCreate method could take some time to inflate the view.

Comment: In the most pessimistic case creation take about 100ms. However I'll probably decide not to protest the user from himself with that issue.